# C++ - Global variable performance when it is likely in the cache

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to understand if my global variable usage which is being done for convenience and ease of assembly generation has a positive side-effect or not (I guess I'm looking to rid myself of the guilt of having these globals).

Program Details:

Broken up into "operations". Each operation reads I/O then does heavy mathematical compute, lots of special casing of code paths via hand-written assembly.

- Single-threaded, will never be multi-threaded
- One global variable, a fixed-size pre-allocated array (128K)
- One global variable, an integer that acts as a pointer

My justification for using global variables here is primarily that I can then just generate call instructions without having to pass parameters, setting up the stack, etc.

The calls will to be functions like this:

```
DoSomething1()
{
   access global1's memory ...
   increment global2 ...

   reset code;
}
```

I can ofcourse generate code for parameters, but then I thought maybe the global variables will likely have a perf benefit as well, since the compiler is going to be a constant address for the access. Of course, my global is extremely likely to be in the cache as well.

Am I thinking about this right? Is it possible that using the global the way I describe will make the compiler try to do load/store as opposed to en register them? In fact, can the compiler en register a global variable?

Comment: You should generate assembly language listings at the highest optimization levels before trying to predict how the compiler will behave.  For example, if the compiler passes values by register, then your optimizations have less effect and you wasted your time.

Comment: The lifetime of a variable in the processors data cache depends on the size of the cache and how often it is accessed.  The variable will be replaced if there is not enough room for other necessary data.